# What is get_phrase function in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I have seen get_phrase function used in many pages. What exactly this function does?

Comment: Have you checked the manual? I'm sure a quick google search for `get_phrase codeigniter` will get you what you're looking for.

Comment: @FrankerZ I have searched twice. Didn't got anything helpful

Comment: Can you give me an example of where you're seeing 'get_phrase'?

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-left">
   <li class="active">
             <a href="#list" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i> 
     <?php echo get_phrase('class_routine_list');?>
                     </a></li>
   <li>
             <a href="#add" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-plus"></i>
     <?php echo get_phrase('add_class_routine');?>

Comment: Where did you find that?

Comment: it is used in a project

Comment: http://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-1066.html          

you can check here

Comment: Yeah: That looks like a personal project. `get_phrase` is probably something he wrote.

Comment: "get_phrase" is used in many projects you can find, but i still don't get how it is used

Comment: Give me another project where this is the case? That's the only post I found with `get_phrase` used in it. (It was also the first post on google)

Comment: https://www.codehive.io/boards/Ksq04Fw

Comment: I've searched the code igniter repository on github. No mention of `get_phrase`. Not quite sure

Comment: thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the answer. get_phrase() function is a string function that converts the first letter to capital letter. get_phrase(hello_world) in converted into Hello World.